# SQL where conditions in-list with multiple item?

Tags: sql, where-clause

I would like to query a table, where i need 2 columns meet certain criteria, as an example, a table like below:

```
LastName FirstName Age address
LN1      FN1        18  ADD1
LN2      FN1        20  ADD2
```

Now I want to extract 1st address like below:

```
select * from mytable
where LastName in 'LN1' and FirstName in 'FN1'
```

Can I use such a condition:

```
where (LastName, FirstName) in (LN1,FN1)
```

please kindly help. thanks.

Comment: yes you can use `where (LastName, FirstName) in ('LN1','FN1')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some databases support the syntax you want:

```
where (LastName, FirstName) in ('LN1', 'FN1')
```

Note that the single quotes are important, because they are string constants.

In other databases, you need to do:

```
where LastName = 'LN1' or FirstName = 'FN1'
```

or perhaps put the constants into a derived table, and use a `join` for the matching.

Comment: To add Signle Quote helps! I am using DB2, and that two columns i use are 'varchar", so single quote is must. Previously I am using double quote ", which not help. thanks!

Comment: Available in Oracle but not SQL Server - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35194028/in-clause-in-sql-server-with-multiple-columns

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `or` or `and`

```
select * from mytable where LastName = 'LN1' or FirstName = 'FN1';
select * from mytable where LastName = 'LN1' and FirstName = 'FN1';
```