# Update rows if their keys are in a set

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-plus

I have a table in SQL Server with a composite primary key and a set of keys of rows that need to be updated. Is it possible to update these rows (e.g. do thing like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35194028/in-clause-in-sql-server-with-multiple-columns/47301855)) using Entity Framework Plus or anything else?

I want something like

```
ctx.Users.Where(x => MySet.Contains(new { x.Col1, x.Col2 }))
         .Update(x => new User() { IsSoftDeleted = 1 });
```

Comment: do you want 1 line like this? or you are fine with few lines?

Comment: @Asherguru, I want it to be as fast as possible. The table may have many rows so preferably they should be updated with one SQL query.